# Nothing happens when connecting to gmail account using Python

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send an email from my raspberry pi on startup to get its IP address. I followed this blog: https://elinux.org/RPi_Email_IP_On_Boot_Debian

My code:

```
__author__ = 'author'
__license__ = "license"
__version__ = "1.0"
__maintainer__ = "maintainer"
__status__ = "Test"

import subprocess
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import datetime

def connect_type(word_list):
    """ This function takes a list of words, then, depeding which key word, returns the corresponding
    internet connection type as a string. ie) 'ethernet'.
    """
    if 'wlan0' in word_list or 'wlan1' in word_list:
        con_type = 'wifi'
    elif 'eth0' in word_list:
        con_type = 'ethernet'
    else:
        con_type = 'current'

    return con_type

# Change to your own account information
# Account Information
to = 'toemail@gmx.com' # Email to send to.
gmail_user = 'myemail@gmail.com' # Email to send from. (MUST BE GMAIL)
gmail_password = 'mypwd' # Gmail password.

try:
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) # Server to use.
    smtpserver.set_debuglevel(1)
    smtpserver.ehlo()  # Says 'hello' to the server
    smtpserver.starttls()  # Start TLS encryption
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)  # Log in to server
    today = datetime.date.today()  # Get current time/date

    arg='ip route list'  # Linux command to retrieve ip addresses.
    # Runs 'arg' in a 'hidden terminal'.
    p=subprocess.Popen(arg,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    data = p.communicate()  # Get data from 'p terminal'.

    # Split IP text block into three, and divide the two containing IPs into words.
    ip_lines = data[0].splitlines()
    split_line_a = ip_lines[1].split()
    split_line_b = ip_lines[2].split()

    # con_type variables for the message text. ex) 'ethernet', 'wifi', etc.
    ip_type_a = connect_type(split_line_a)
    ip_type_b = connect_type(split_line_b)

    """Because the text 'src' is always followed by an ip address,
    we can use the 'index' function to find 'src' and add one to
    get the index position of our ip.
    """
    ipaddr_a = split_line_a[split_line_a.index('src')+1]
    ipaddr_b = split_line_b[split_line_b.index('src')+1]

    # Creates a sentence for each ip address.
    my_ip_a = 'Your %s ip is %s' % (ip_type_a, ipaddr_a)
    my_ip_b = 'Your %s ip is %s' % (ip_type_b, ipaddr_b)

    # Creates the text, subject, 'from', and 'to' of the message.
    msg = MIMEText(my_ip_a + "\n" + my_ip_b)
    msg['Subject'] = 'IPs For RaspberryPi on %s' % today.strftime('%b %d %Y')
    msg['From'] = gmail_user
    msg['To'] = to
    # Sends the message
    smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, [to], msg.as_string())
    # Closes the smtp server.
    smtpserver.quit()
except Exception as e:
    print ("[ERROR] failed to send mail: " + str(e))
```

when executing the program, no exception occurs. however, the program tries to connect to the server forever at line

```
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
```

and nothing happens.

I can reach the smtp server and port using telnet without any problem. I also enabled *less secure apps* in my Gmail account.

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you make sure your raspberry pi can access internet in the first place on startup?

Comment: It is connected with an ethernet cable. I havent even tried on startup. I only ran it from command line so far.